# pagination using cloud firestore in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net, google-cloud-firestore, pagination, datagrid, syncfusion

I am trying to implement **pagination, filtering, searching** using **cloud firestore in ASP.NET Core ( Syncfusion:DataGrid )** by using **DataManagerRequest** and **UrlAdaptor**. I know how to do that using SQL and entity framework, but it is different from this because firestore works very differently.

Below is the method called automatically from the grid (via ajax). I am not worried about the front end at all. Also, I think probably I should use firestore API instead of syncfusion (I used syncfusion api for the data that is store in MSSQL and it works perfectly but filtering and querying API is very different in firestore from entity framework API or the raw SQL syntax).

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> UrlDatasourceAsync([FromBody] DataManagerRequest dm)
    {
        CollectionReference collection = _firestore.Collection("students"); 
        Query query;

        if (dm.Search != null && dm.Search.Count > 0)
        {
            //DataSource = operation.PerformSearching(DataSource, dm.Search);  //Search
        }
        if (dm.Sorted != null && dm.Sorted.Count > 0) //Sorting
        {
            //DataSource = operation.PerformSorting(DataSource, dm.Sorted);
        }
        if (dm.Where != null && dm.Where.Count > 0) //Filtering
        {
            //DataSource = operation.PerformFiltering(DataSource, dm.Where, dm.Where[0].Operator);
        }
        int count = (await collection.GetSnapshotAsync()).Count();
        if (dm.Skip != 0)
        {
            //DataSource = operation.PerformSkip(DataSource, dm.Skip);   //Paging
        }
        if (dm.Take != 0)
        {
            //DataSource = operation.PerformTake(DataSource, dm.Take);
        }

        query = collection.Limit(dm.Take == 0 ? 10 : dm.Take);

        var list = new List<StudentViewModel>();
        foreach (DocumentSnapshot doc in await query.GetSnapshotAsync())
        {
            list.Add(doc.ConvertTo<StudentViewModel>());
        }


        var ss = new JsonSerializerSettings();
        ss.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();

        return dm.RequiresCounts ? Json(new { result = list, count = count }, ss) : Json(list);
    }
}
```

grid code in razor file:

```
<ejs-grid id="Grid" allowPaging="true" allowSorting="true" allowFiltering="true" toolbar="@(new List<string>() { "Search"})" load="actionComplete" created="gridCreated" dataBound="actionComplete" actionComplete="actionComplete" actionBegin="actionBegin">

            <e-grid-filterSettings type="Excel"> </e-grid-filterSettings>

            <e-grid-pagesettings pageSize="10" pageSizes="true"></e-grid-pagesettings>

            <e-data-manager url="@Url.Action("UrlDatasource","RegisteredStudents")" adaptor="UrlAdaptor"></e-data-manager>

            <e-grid-columns>

                <e-grid-column field="Name" headerText="Name"></e-grid-column>

                <e-grid-column field="AttendantCategry" headerText="Attendant Categry"></e-grid-column>

                <e-grid-column field="StudentClassification" headerText="Student Classification"></e-grid-column>

                <e-grid-column field="Major" headerText="Major" width="160"></e-grid-column>

                <e-grid-column field="Phone" headerText="Phone"></e-grid-column>

                <e-grid-column field="SignUpDate" headerText="Sign Up Date" customFormat="@(new {type = "datetime", format = "M/d/y hh:mm a" })"></e-grid-column>

                @*<e-grid-column headerText="" template="#template"></e-grid-column>*@

            </e-grid-columns>

        </ejs-grid>



<script>

    function gridCreated() {

        var grid = document.getElementById("Grid").ej2_instances[0];

        grid.hideSpinner = () => true;

        ej.popups.setSpinner({ type: 'Bootstrap' });

        $(".e-spinner-pane").css("display", "block");

    }



    function actionComplete() {

        $(".e-spinner-pane").css("display", "none");

    }



    function actionBegin() {

        $(".e-spinner-pane").css("display", "block");

    }



    document.getElementById('clear').addEventListener('click', () => {

        var gridObj = document.getElementById("Grid").ej2_instances[0];

        gridObj.searchSettings.key = '';

    });

</script>
```

Thank you

Comment: Are you using REST API or Firebase Admin SDK ?

Comment: I installed the package Google.Cloud.Firestore. Here is the official link: https://googleapis.dev/dotnet/Google.Cloud.Firestore/2.4.0/index.html

Comment: Can you provide some code that you've tried so far or where you will be using this ?

Comment: @Dharmaraj, I updated the post and included the code I am trying to implement. I have similar piece of code for MSSQL data which is perfectly working but firestore is a different story. Appreciate your help.